# Passing String to Main from a function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_name();
void display_name(char *fullname);



int main(void)
{

 char first[80];
 char second[80];
 char *fullname[80];



get_name();
display_name(*fullname);



 system("pause");

 return 0;

}

void get_name()
{
 char first[80];
 char second[80];
 char *fullname[80];


 printf("Please enter first name: ");
 scanf("%s", &first);



 printf("\nPlease enter last name: ");
 scanf("%s", &second);



 strcpy(*fullname, first);
 strcat(*fullname, " ");
 strcat(*fullname, second);

 printf("\n\nFull name is : %s ", *fullname);

}


void display_name(char *fullname)
{

    int index;
    char check;
    int count=0;
    printf("\n\nFull name is : %s ", fullname); //check to see if string is passes correctly 

    for(index=0; fullname[index] != '\0'; index++)
    {
        check=fullname[index];



        if(check != ' ')
        {
            count++;
        }


    }

    printf("\n\nNumber of characters in string is: %i\n", count);
}
```

im trying to send the string from get_name() to display name to count the number of characters. Everytime i pass the string, its comes out as gibberish. Am i passing wrong? I need to use one function to get the first and last name and concatenate the full name, then use another function to count the number of characters.

Comment: Why an array of pointers? `char *fullname[80];` --> `char fullname[160];` , 79 + 79 + 1 space + the trailing NUL

Comment: [Function Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1006/function-parameters#t=201611180623366898669)

Comment: `get_name` is not modifying the `fullname` variable inside main, so `display_name` is passed an uninitialised char array, hence the gibberish.

Answer (score 2):

You're using pointers and `scanf` quite wrongly.

First of all `scanf` argument to for `%s` is supposed to be an array of characters. Remember that the array is in fact the pointer to the array.

Second you declare `fullname` to be an array of 80 pointers which is probably not what you want to do. Especially when you don't allocate the space for the string.

Instead it should be something like:

```
void get_name()
{
  char first[80];
  char second[80];
  char fullname[80]; // an array of chars instead of pointers

  printf("Please enter first name: ");
  scanf("%s", first); // not taking the address of first - is already an address

  printf("\nPlease enter last name: ");
  scanf("%s", second); // not taking the address of second - is already an address

  strcpy(fullname, first); // don't dereference fullname
  strcat(fullname, " "); // don't dereference fullname
  strcat(fullname, second); // don't dereference fullname

  printf("\n\nFull name is : %s ", fullname); // don't dereference fullname

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The declarations of variables are local to the scope where they are declared.
IOW when you declare first, second and fullname in your function `get_name`, they are local to that function. In order to pass the value outside of the function you have two, no three ways to do this starting with the worst way:

(1) declare the variable global, i.e. outside of main then share that variable in your function(s).

(2) declare the variable in main but pass it to the function who then fills in the string

```
int main()
{
   char fullname[80];
   get_name(fullname,sizeof(fullname)); // good to tell function avail size
...

void get_name(char* fullname, size_t length)
{
...
```

(3) Allocate memory on the heap, heap memory can be passed around between functions via a pointer

```
int main()
{
   char* fullname = NULL;
   get_name(&fullname);
...

void get_name(char** fullname)
{
  *fullname = malloc(80); 
...
```

**EDIT**

In order to read strings from the keyboard it is better to use fgets()

```
char buffer[128];
if (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin) != NULL) {
  // remove the \n
  char* p = strchr(buffer,'\n');
  if ( p != NULL ) { 
    *p = '\0';
  }
}
```

Using `scanf` reading from the keyboard is to be avoided, if you need to extract information use instead `sscanf` on the string read with `fgets`

Comment: I can't use global variables.